# In ASP.NET, is it possible to have a page with multiple user controls refresh its controls individually?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working in ASP.NET.

I have page with 5 user controls, each user control contains one grid. Each grid is populated by data requested by a WCF call.

Each WCF call could take up to 30 seconds, but it could be finished in as little as a second.

I am wondering if its possible to set it up so that each control renders instantly, as soon as the result comes back from WCF, without waiting for all of the other controls to obtain their data via WCF and render themselves.

**What I have tried**

I've tried doing the population of the grids on a separate thread started in `Page_Load`, however the grid remains empty for some reason.

Comment: You can try calling that webservice from client script on page load and update those controls with incoming data instead of filling that data while sending the page from server.

Comment: you could try rendering the grids in client side using Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just placing each user control inside an [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). That way you each panel can be rendered individually.

I've used this technique on a site, where individual panels where needed to be refereshed at defined intervals without needing the whole page to refresh.

I used a timer to refresh the panels, similar to this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).